# How do I mock an object of a class with parameterized constructor?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, powermockito

For the code

```
public class A{
    public A (B b, C c){
    //do something here
    }
}
```

For testing, I wanted to create a mock object. What I am doing now is

```
B bmock = mock(B);
C cmock = mock(C);
A aobject = new A(bmock, cmock);
```

However, this doesn't allow me call verify() on aobject as it is not mocked. How to do that?

Comment: Why would you want to call `verify` on an `A` if `A` is what you're testing?

Comment: that makes sense. But I intend to verify that aobject is calling some other function as it should. I was doing verify(aobject, times(1)).somefunction();

Comment: Don't use mocks for that. Make your method change or return some state and verify that with assertions.

Comment: If you need to verify that class A calls a method, this method should be on one of the dependencies (i.e. class B or C). You shouldn't be making things visible for testing - test behaviour, not implementation.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a `Spy`:

```
A aobject = spy(new A(bmock, cmock));
```

So you are actually calling the implementation of `A` but can still verify interactions.

See the doc for details:
http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#spy(T)